# Не отрисовывается переключение radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

На форме в таблицу c помощью хелпера генерируется следующая разметка, массив переключателей с несколькими вариантами ответа (за - против - и тд), для простоты оставил 2 варианта.

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="active btn btn-default">
            <input checked="checked" name="Question1.QuestionDecision" type="radio" value="1">За
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input name="Question1.QuestionDecision" type="radio" value="2">Против
        </label>
    </div>
</td>
```

Нумерация после Question произвольная, там id. Мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку выбрать на всей странице например второй вариант. Делаю так

```
function SelectAll() {
    $("input[name^='Question']").removeAttr('checked');
    $("input[name^='Question'][value='2']").attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Проблема в том что в разметке атрибут `cheked` появляется, но не отображается само нажатие кнопки

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить

`$("input[name^='Question'][value='2']").attr('checked', 'checked');`

на

`$("input[name^='Question'][value='2']").prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Так даже разметку не меняет